# C# Button with Image does not get 'pushed' in when clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, image, button

I'm dabbling in C#,and I'm rather inexperienced with it. I have a button with text and an image on it. When I run the program and press the button, the button gets pushed in, along with the text, but the Image stays static.

Does anyone know a workaround?

*EDIT:

```
    this.btnRename.AllowDrop = true;
    this.btnRename.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
    this.btnRename.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.None;
    this.btnRename.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("btnRename.Image")));
    this.btnRename.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
    this.btnRename.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(675, 3);
    this.btnRename.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
    this.btnRename.Name = "btnRename";
    this.btnRename.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(55, 48);
    this.btnRename.TabIndex = 7;
    this.btnRename.Text = "&Rename";
    this.btnRename.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
    this.btnRename.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
    this.btnRename.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnRename_Click);
```

Comment: The text is supposed to be static too.  Open the Designer.cs file, find the code that initializes the button and post it in your question.

Comment: I dont know exactly what you want to do. do you want the image to move 1 pixel to the left-right? If so, why would you want such a behaviour? Try clicking a normal button with just text, the text stays static, too. I would recommend you to just let the .net framework together with the OS decide for how buttons should be rendered and how the clicking effects should behave. That creates a common look and feel of all apps running under that OS.

Comment: What I mean, is that when you press the button, the button and text get indented as if you actually push the button. That same behaviour does not work with the image.

Comment: On my PC (Windows 7) the button's text doesnt get indented when i push it... So, the image should not move as well to have a consistent behaviour.

Comment: write a function of click event of button.

Comment: Don't know what the rest of these guys are doing, but for me, text does indeed get pushed down and to the right when the button is clicked - seems to be 1 pixel - but the image stays static.  If it's really not happening for them, maybe it's an OS setting, but I can't imagine a button where the text doesn't move.

KrisTrip's solution below seems to work well.

Comment: I agree w/ OP and Enos, on my Windows button text moves r/d; both in non-.NET buttons (Open File dialog) & in Forms.Button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET doesn't do this for you automatically because it doesn't know what you expect to happen to the image on button click. Do you expect it to be smaller, moved right, moved left...etc. Perhaps you could implement the MouseDown and MouseUp events? On MouseDown you could have it change the image to what you expect to see for the "pushed in" and change it back on MouseUp. Of course this involves you essentially having 2 images, a "clicking" and an "normal" version.

Comment: that'll be resource-hell to maintain though... I'd opt for an imagehandler if you really would want that (like: MouseDown = imageclone + 1px margin or something)

Comment: I don't buy this answer; what I'd expect seems pretty obvious, do the same thing with the image as with text: move r/d. I'd guess .NET doesn't do this because they didn't bother/notice.

Comment: I guess I should have said something more like .NET "probably" doesn't do this because...I'm not claiming to have any inside knowledge of Microsoft. The point of the answer was to suggest a way to get the same functionality. Another option is to use WPF instead of WinForms which allows you to perform transforms.

Comment: having two separate icons contributes to bloat, so I'm not too much in favour of it. However the WPF idea is interesting and I'll try implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a custom image button. What I did was to simulate 'button flashing' by overriding the `OnMouseDown` event handler.

```cs
protected override void OnMouseDown(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnMouseDown(e);

  var g = this.CreateGraphics();
  var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 128, 128, 128));
  g.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

The flashing is simulated by painting a semi-transparent rectangle on the button. The `Thread.Sleep()` is needed because otherwise I could not see the effect.